# Sanitize input for SQL using Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm aware of Quote and QuoteInto. Neither of which can help me with the following. I need to sanitize the input for the following SQL:

```
select * from log where message like '%bla%'
```

QuoteInto and Quote will add quotes that won't work with the % (wildcards). How do I sanitize this input so I end up with a "safe" SQL statement as above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Append the `%` characters directly to your variable, and quote the entire value.
That would look something like this:

```
 $value = 'bla';
 $db->quoteInto("SELECT * FROM log WHERE message LIKE ?", "%{$value}%");
```

As compared to this, which gives you the bad results you described:

```
 $value = 'bla';
 $db->quoteInto("SELECT * FROM log WHERE message LIKE '%?%'", $value);
```